# Why is my DIV falling down the page

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical menu and when i add content to the page the added content is coming below the menu.I want to prevent the content from falling over.Expecting help from experts here.

In the given example i want demo in same line as my menu.

```css
p, ul, li, div, nav
            {
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }
    
            body
            {
                font-family:Calibri;
            }
    
            #menu {
                overflow: auto;
                position:relative;
                z-index:2;
            }
    
            .parent-menu 
            {
                background-color: #0c8fff;
                width:200px;
                
            }
    
            #menu ul
            {
                list-style-type:none;
            }
    
            #menu ul li a
            {
                padding:10px 15px;
                display:block;
                color:#fff;
                text-decoration:none;
            }
    
                #menu ul li a:hover
                {
                    background-color:#007ee9;
                }
    
                #menu ul li:hover > ul {
                    left: 200px;
                    -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
                    -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
                    -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
                    transition: left 200ms ease-in;
                }
    
                #menu ul li > ul {
                    position: absolute;
                    background-color: #333;
                    top: 0;
                    left: -200px;
                    min-width: 200px;
                    z-index: -1;
                    height: 100%;
                    -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
                    -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
                    -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
                    transition: left 200ms ease-in;
                }
    
                #menu ul li > ul li a:hover
                {
                    background-color:#2e2e2e;
                }
    .content {
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
     font-size: 0.8em;
     line-height: 1.65em;
    
        border-left: 1px solid #bdc1a3;
             border-right: 1px solid #bdc1a3;
     background-color:#ffffff
    }
    #dataDiv{
      float: left;border:1px solid #bdc1a3;background-color:#f3f5dc;
    }
```

```html
<div class="content">   
    <div id="menu" style="overflow:hidden">
        <ul class="parent-menu">
       <li><a href='#'><span>Menu1</span></a>
          <ul>
             <li><a href='#'><span>SubMenu1</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='#'><span>SubMenu2</span></a></li>
           </ul>
            </li>   
       
       <li><a href='#'><span>LOG OUT</span></a></li>
       
    </ul>
       </div>
            <div id="dataDiv"  style="overflow:hidden">
    
    <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: #0C9FFF">
                            &nbsp;Demo
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table> 
                        </div>
```

Comment: ... just learn the basics about a layout. There a tons of tutorials all over the internet.

Comment: sorry mate just a toddler in ui design...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the style attribute `float`.
https://jsfiddle.net/4g5tLekm/7/

Modify `<div id="menu" style="overflow:hidden">` to `<div id="menu" style="overflow:hidden;float:left">`

Comment: working in the sample code...but when integrated into my project its not working.Menu is defined in a master page(aspx)

Comment: Please add the style in your CSS file. Add `float:left;` to `#menu` in CSS

Answer (score 2):

Your  menu is in a `div`, which is a block-level element so it takes up the entire width of it's parent element and will push the following content underneath it.

One way to achieve what you're trying to do is to add `float: left` to your `#menu`.

Comment: I tried but didn't worked.If possible can you please update the jsfiddle

Comment: I just copied your code above and added `float: left` to `#menu`:  https://jsfiddle.net/44jnaw9g/

Comment: working in the sample code...but when integrated into my project its not working.Menu is defined in a master page(aspx)